# get the currently selected option in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to get the currently selected option in a dropdown menu with javascript. but i cant seem to get it to work

my current js:

```
var itemqual = $("select#itemqual option:selected").text();
var type = "hat";
$('select#itemtype').change(function() {
if(itemtype == type) {
    $('#graphic').show();
} else {
    $('#graphic').hide();
}
});
```

however when I change the selection it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Javascript should work for you.

```
var type = "hat";
$('select#itemtype').change(function() {
    if($("select#itemtype option:selected").text() == type) {
        $('#graphic').show();
    } else {
        $('#graphic').hide();
    }
});
```